# Passing optional closure to the View

Tags: swift, swiftui, closures

I created a new subview containing a header for the other views.
It has an arrow icon and i wanna pass a closure to this subview (profileClose is a function):

```
PlainHeader(title: getLocalizedText("edit profile"), action: profileClose)
```

The problem is I want this closure to be optional.. So i decided to wrap it into `() ? = nil` but after i did it every time i am using `PlainHeader(...)`. Xcode says `"Extra argument 'action' in call"`

```
import SwiftUI

struct PlainHeader: View {
    var title: String
    let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        
            ZStack {
                
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("arrow-back")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 18, height: 7)
                            .padding(.leading, 31)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("[debugUI] action called")
                        if self.action != nil {
                            self.action!()
                        }
                    }
                }
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(title)")
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 280)
                            .font(.custom(Font.primaryTextFont, size: 20))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.mainSubtitleColor)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
        }
        .frame(height: 80)
        
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I just wanna use it with and without closure.. so i set it as optional and give it a default value nil..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your variable let to var.

```
var action: (() -> Void)? = nil
```

Answer (score 4):

The problems is here:

```
let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
```

You declared it as `let` and instantly set it to `nil` so it is not available to be initialized again.

You can either declare it as `var` or better still write an initialiser:

```
struct PlainHeader: View {
    private let title: String
    private let action: (() -> Void)?

    public init(title: String,
                action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
    }
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: @ LuLuGaGa: why you used "public init" ? the single "init" does the job done i think. let me know why, or what I am missing?

Comment: init is fine as well.

Comment: Shouldn't the action be marked as @escaping in the initialiser?

Comment: Optional function parameter is @escaping by default